# Magento catalog price rule disappears

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I'm getting same problem as mentioned below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/magento-catalog-price-rule-disappears-at-night

I applied the solution provided by Alexei Yerofeyev, but now it will giving me an error as 'unable to apply rules'.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all You might need to do `reindexing`. Please reindex once then check it is working or not.

Ensure that your Magento cron is setup correctly: [Installing and Verifying Magento: Setting Up Cron Jobs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron)

- Check if the cron-job is running
- look into cron_schedule-db-table
- use /cron.php to refresh
- delete `/var/cache` for changes in `etc/config.xml` cron-sections (not
  sure to also truncate db-table)
- Check if price-calculation happens after indexing.

  "After the indexed price is saved into the index table this events triggers an observer method, which updates the index table with catalog rule adjusted prices. Because of this fact it is important to make sure that the Mage_CatalogRule module’s cronjob, which calculates rule prices for the current day, is run before the daily product price indexer." http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-catalog-price-rules/